# Serial communication to Arduino via node-red sends in "wrong" format

Tags: arduino, serial-port, node-red

I have two Arduinos hooked together via ports 8 and 9 and trying to communicate between them using SoftwareSerial and a Node-red server.  The first Arduino is connected to a computer running node-red and running this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

int incomingByte;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    mySerial.print(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

The second Arduino is connected to another computer running the serial monitor and running this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

int incomingByte;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    incomingByte = mySerial.read();
    Serial.println(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

The node-red sketch is very simple and is just an inject into a serial out.  The inject just sets `msg.payload` to "H".  I have another one that sets it to "L".  When I press the inject, I get the following from the H via the serial monitor:

```
55
50
```

When I inject the "L" I get the following:

```
55
54
```

And when I tried injecting "HELLO", I get this:

```
55
50
54
57
55
54
55
54
55
57
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I expected to get something that is equivalent to "H" in some way.  Node-red serial output is configured with 9600 baud as defined in the code.

[image: Node-red screenshot]

Comment: Please update the question with details about how you are sending the `H` to the serial-out node

Comment: Have you got the serial port configuration in the serial port config node set to match what the arduino is expecting?

Comment: Yes, both are set to 9600 baud with the other defaults left alone - 8 bit, no parity, 1 bit stop.

Comment: Don't try to debug both sides of a comm at once.  Hook one to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problems.  The first issue was that I was using SoftwareSerial `mySerial.print` which seems to act differently than `Serial.print`.  Changing it to `mySerial.write` gave me 72 for "H" and 76 for "L" from the serial monitor, which I recognized as an ASCII code.  Then it was just changing `int incomingByte` to `char incomingByte` which then gave me the proper output of "H" and "L".

Comment: "mySerial.write gave me 72" really? it was mySerial.print, not write. print converts number to text. write sends the byte as it is.

Answer (score 0):

sending arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

String incomingByte;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
//  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
//    incomingByte = Serial.read();
//    mySerial.print(incomingByte);
//  }
  mySerial.write(incomingByte);
}
```

recieving arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX

String incomingByte;

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  }
}
```

make sure you have
sending arduino pin 9 connected to receiving arduino pin 8 and
sending arduino pin 8 connected to receiving arduino pin 9